# Как картинку положить вниз?

Tags: css

Прошу подсказать по такому вопросу.

Мне необходимо сделать фон из нескольких картинок. Одна из которых должна быть полупрозрачной. вставлял картинку в боди как background-image и давал ей opacity , потом дети наследовали прозрачность. Прописывать каждому элементу дабы он не наследовал это значение не охота(слишком много), в связи с этим решил картинку вставить просто как изображение и дал ему позишин абсолют, чтобы он не мешал другим элементам. По началу понравился такой вариант, но возникла проблемка. Этак картинка влезла как самый верхний слой. То есть она полупрозрачное, всё хорошо-не мешает смотреть, но ссылке как бы оказались под ней-не нажимаются, текст тоже под ней-не выделяется.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно просто положить данную картинку на самый нижний слой?

Comment: background-position: bottom;

Comment: Придумал небольшой костыль, но всё равно не панацея. Обернул всё в ещё один див(у боди есть свой фон уже), дал картинку как фон, но беда маленькая. Картинка смотрится хорошо и лежит как фон, НО все элементы стали наследовать полу прозрачность. Кто знает как можно отменить наследование свойства через родителя, а-то писать у всех детей отдельно как-то слишком длинно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте верхним элементам `z-index` выше, чем у картинки (хотя бы 1). И не забудьте указать `position:relative;`. Как вариант, можете все закатать в `#wrapper` и работать с ним.